# How to set up jEdit for sbt build error highlighting?

Tags: scala, sbt, jedit

I currently experimenting with different lightweight text editors for Scala development. [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) seems to enable the user to make many tweaks. However, I'm currently having a problem with its error and warning highlighting via the Console plugin.

It marks some lines as errors without actually being them so. That's why I wanted to hear if anybody actually has a configuration of the sbt error patterns that they would share with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
Error: \[error\](\s)(\w):([\\|\w|.]*):(\d*):(\s)([\w*|(\s)|\W]*)

Warn: \[warn\](\s)(\w):([\\|\w|.]*):(\d*):(\s)([\w*|(\s)|\W]*)

Extra: 

Filename: $3

Line number: $4

Error message: $6
```